# Need Suggestion On Designing a Table Pagination

Tags: java, javascript, performance, jquery

**Problem Statement :** In a Oracle Table I have 3000000 of record. User want to see this table in Browser as a table (jquery data table) with pagination (100 records per page).When I designed it comes around 30000 pages.When User Clicks a Single page I am query the table with ordering show it will return that many rows. The problem here is it takes some time around 20 seconds to load each page.

Can anybody suggest me "How to tackle this scenario?So That User will not feel slowness from his side.Is caching in server side of these many records is a good option or not?"

The Query is similar to:

```
SELECT /*+ ALL_ROWS */ * FROM 
(SELECT ROWNUM SNO , A.* FROM 
( SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(ABCTABLE 4)*/ COUNT(*) OVER ( ) CNT, 
            columnA, columnb,columnc
             FROM ABCTABLE )
       order by columnA, columnb,columnc ) a )
       where sno between ? and ?;
```

? and ? :- is page range 1 to 30/30 to 60/.....

Answer (score 1):

I still doubt your GUI user will see all the 3000000 record. Definitely he is interested in latest rows (filter) around 1000 records (10 pages), So you can better pass first 1000 records to client, and let the client shows 100 records in each page till 10 pages. After that you can ping Server for next 1000 records.

If the delay is in ORACLE fetching, think about indexing of your table to reduce the query timing. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39006/Overview-of-SQL-Server-2005-2008-Table-Indexing-Pa

Also double check with [explain plan](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_interpreting_explain_plan.html).

Comment: @sugumar , Filtering 1000 records from 3000000 is also taking time.User want to see the pages in milli seconds.

Comment: Have you at least run the query in Oracle directly to see how long that part takes?

Comment: +1 Yes, I agree with ElectricLlama; Check first how your DB responding ?

Comment: already indexes are  present .I am using oracle 10g.In the table 200 column are present and one of the column is having xmlType data which 1 mb each.

Comment: @sandeeppatel Could you please tell us the execution time in sqlplus for fetching 1000 rows? also paste your client query in you question.

Comment: Yes I run the query in oracle db directly It is taking 10 seconds. when I have used as prepared statement and showing it it is taking 40 seconds.

Comment: paste your example query here; also table constraints

Comment: @sandeeppatel Also tell us the data types of the column; and constraints you mentioned on that columns.

Comment: I suggest you remove the java tag (is this a javascript web app or a thick client java app?) and add in an Oracle tag if you want some more Oracle help.

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance you first need to find the bottleneck. It could be a number of things:

1. The query returns slowly due to a bad query plan/lack of indexes etc.
2. The data returns slowly due to slow network
3. The data is rendered slowly in your application

No one wants to browse through 3 million records. People are looking for something. If you add some reasonable search/filtering criteria and index on that you will get a more usable application.

Comment: I am using indexes.The query also has Oracle Query optimization hints like /*+PARALLEL (<tablename> 4), /*+PARTITION etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the screen limits to show you only 30 records.

Idea is to show 30 records to user as user cant see 30000 record in hole screen he has to scroll down to see rest of the records.

when he scroll down try fetch next 30 records till you reach 30000 records in per page.

You can use limit in Sql query to limit the number of records rather fetch all records, it will reduce the page load time.

have base limit like this way  1 to 30000, 30001 to 60000 and so on per page.

then on each scroll have SQL limit of 1 to 30

sql_limit = base_limit + 30

if user scroll down to end of 30th record then fetch new 30 records

sql_limit+30

continue this process till you reach page limit which 30000

till sql_limit >= page_limit

if sql_limit exceed page_limit then jumped to new page and do same process again of each page.